# Why am I getting this Google Play optimization tip

Tags: android, google-play, publish

After publishing my app, I got these two confusing Optimization tips:

> **Translate Product descriptions into English (United States) and English (United Kingdom)**
>
> You translated the APK into English (United States) and English
>   (United Kingdom) but not the store listing.
>
> **Add localized graphics for English (United States) and English (United Kingdom)**
>
> You have already translated your store listing or APK into English
>   (United States) and English (United Kingdom). Localized graphics could
>   help these users better understand what your app does.

- My store listing of this app is in one language ONLY: Arabic.
- My APK have only the default res folders and files. No language specific folders or files (like values-en folder) were added.

So, why am I getting these optimization tips? Is it because Google Play expect each app to support English by default?

Comment: Same here but for German, idk where this is coming from

Comment: I'm also getting it: "You have already translated your store listing or APK into English (United Kingdom), Portuguese (Brazil) and Hungarian." My app is english only, the store listing has not been translated.